# Usefulness of non-upper case \mathcal symbols?

Tags: mathcal

I'd like to understand the purpose of `mathcal` for arguments that aren't upper-case letters. For example, `\mathcal{2}` gives ∈ and `\mathcal{p}` gives √.

I tested it for all numbers and lower-case letters, but didn't find any pattern behind them. Does this happen due to a bug or is there an automatic correspondence of sorts?

P.S.: I came across several questions complaining about the abscence of stylish lower-case letters in `mathcal`, but this isn't what I'm asking about (even though it makes no sense to me).

Comment: The same font that is used for `\mathcal` is also used for other symbols.

Comment: Hope mathcal font especially derived for all uppercase alphabets not for digits and other characters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Heiko noted in the comment, the same font used for `\mathcal` is used for other symbols. In fact, `\mathcal` essentially selects the `\symsymbols` font family (which is family number 2).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\verb!\mathcal!: $\mathcal{ABCabc012}$

\verb!\fam=\symsymbols!: $\fam=\symsymbols ABCabc012$
\end{document}
```

[image]